# PHP function in wordpress removing slashes

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on Wordpress theme , the theme stores custom Javascript to the database by `update_post_meta()` hook as post `metadata`. But the problem is that, the **PHP** `file_get_contents()` is removing backslashes abnormally.

The `PHP` function I am using in `functions.php` in Wordpress

```
function add_template($post_id){

    $custom_javascript = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'custom_javascript', true );

    $template_js = file_get_contents(get_template_directory_uri(). '/template/prism.js');

    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'custom_javascript',  $template_js );
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'add_template' );
```

One Error:

Original Javascript: `(^|[^\\])\/\*[\s\S]*?(?:\*\/|$)`

Modified Javascript: `(^|[^\])/*[sS]*?(?:*/|$)`

How to get rid of this issue? Any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that it's `file_get_contents` that removes slashes? If you put that text into database, then your `\\` gets parsed and ends up as single `\`. Try `addslashes` to escape slashes in string

Comment: yes- either putting the string in variable `$custom_javascript`, or if used directly through `update_post_meta( $post_id, 'custom_javascript',   file_get_contents(get_template_directory_uri(). '/template/prism.js' ))`;  it strips back-slashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to add [`addslashes()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) function.

So, the working **PHP** code for wordpress would be -

```
function add_template($post_id){

    $custom_javascript = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'custom_javascript', true );

    $template_js = file_get_contents(get_template_directory_uri(). '/template/prism.js');

    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'custom_javascript',  addslashes($template_js ));
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'add_template' );
```

> Or in Short

```
function add_template($post_id){

    $custom_javascript = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'custom_javascript', true );

   update_post_meta( $post_id, 'custom_javascript',  addslashes(file_get_contents(get_template_directory_uri(). '/template/prism.js' )));
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'add_template' );
```

Comment: For long term, and increased value, please explain why adding this function solves the user's issue. This way future visitors can quickly learn from your answer, without requiring them to visit an external link to learn why the function is necessary to solve the issue. Better Explanations also result in more upvotes, as visitors absorb knowledge quicker, to apply to their own code issues. Code only answers are generally discouraged on SO. Thanks for the documentation link - people are more apt to visit when given a quick blurb.